# How to handle functional component error?

Tags: reactjs

The component accepts a string in the process and tries to convert it to a regular expression.

```
function ControlString(props) {
    const regExp = new RegExp(props.template, "g");
    ...
}
```

The update is called for each input character, so if in the parent to try to enter '\ d', the constructor will generate an error on the single oblique line

In functions, componentDidCatch does not work. How can I handle this exception without translating the entire component into a class?

Comment: How about try/catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a function which 'validates' your RegExp:

```
const isValidRegExp = (regExp) => {
    try {
        new RegExp(regExp);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

At the top of your component you call the function and opt out early if the RegExp is invalid:

```
function ControlString(props) {
    if(!isValidRegExp(props.template)) {
        return null;
    }
}
```